# How to make an OR Function only display one result

Tags: sql, ms-access

For example, I have two columns, Date and Hours and from a variety of dates, I only want it to display one result.

```
SELECT Day, Hours
FROM Hours
WHERE (Day)=#2021-04-22# OR (Day)=#2021-04-23#;
```

Displays

```
Day         Hours
2021-04-22  9
2021-04-22  2
2021-04-23  6
2021-04-23  3
```

But I would like for it to only choose to display one of the two dates.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Also what data types are your columns `Day` and `Hours`. Please also include the `Expected output` with the `Actual output` you have already provided so we can see what you are trying to produce.

Comment: which one to display? less hours or more hours?

Comment: Day is using Dates & Times, Hours is using Number.

I am using Microsoft Access, and I would like for it to just query one of the two options randomly and display its hours.

Comment: I believe Access supports `Top`.  `SELECT TOP 1 Day, Hours FROM...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Timer()* function to alternate the selection of the two dates for the selection of the date to appear random:

```sql
Select 
    [Day], Hours
From 
    Hours
Where 
    [Day] = (
            Select Top 1 [Day] 
            From Hours
            Where [Day] In (#2021-04-22#, #2021-04-23#)
            Order By [Day] * (1 - 2 * (Timer() * 100 Mod 2))
            )
```

`Timer() * 100` returns a new even or uneven integer every 1/100 second. The fancy expression returns `[Day] * 1` or `[Day] * -1`, thus the sorting and then the top selected Day will alter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Select TOP N is used to specify to display only N number of records. In this example, it will return only one record and select the day and hours (2 rows)

```
SELECT Day, Hours
FROM Hours
WHERE Day = (
            SELECT TOP 1 Day FROM Hours
            WHERE (Day)=#2021-04-22# OR (Day)=#2021-04-23#
            )
```